# Joomla 3.3 - assign a module to specific pages fails

Tags: joomla-3.x

In the backend under module manager - name of module - menu assignment, you can assign a module to specific pages. But when I try to select some pages and save, it saves it as no pages. The only setting that doesn't do this is all pages. Have any of you experienced similar problems? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Have you ensured you're using the latest version of Joomla (3.3.6)? Have you by any chance modified any core Joomla files?

Comment: I am using version 3.3.4 and I have not modified any core Joomla files

Comment: then update to 3.3.6 and if this persists report back

Answer (score 2):

Solved updating to Joomla v3.3.6, answer via @FFrewin

Comment: @Magesoe please award the green tick to this answer to mark this page as resolved.